# How to make uTorrent bypass VPN and connect directly? (otherwise it will consume my VPN quota)

Tags: windows, vpn, bittorrent, torrent

Internet is full of recipes on how to prevent ISP throttling and make uTorrent use VPN.

My case is completely opposite: I need VPN to bypass *Great Russian Firewall* - since my government pretty much doesn't care that you download a movie or two, but has a strong opinion on what you should and shouldn't read online. So I need VPN for my browser and apps for mobile devices, but I don't need uTorrent to consume my VPN quota.

The best I could find is Microsoft's [article on auto-triggered VPN](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2013/10/03/automatically-triggering-vpn-connections-and-vpn-diagnostics-enhancements-in-windows-8-1.aspx) - you tell Windows to quietly enable VPN as soon as whitelisted app (browser or news application, or RSS reader) starts. But I don't have any idea whether uTorrent running in the background will use that VPN connection as well.

I will even be satisfied with the solution that will make HTTP/HTTPS traffic flow through VPN, leaving everything else as is.

Any ideas or hints how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about policy circumvention.

Comment: @EEAA, "policy circumvention" clause refers to the stuff such as avoiding filters on the workplace. And I am writing about government censorship, which is not a "policy" thing, but a free speech issue.

Comment: Actually that is not true. Policy circumvention is what it is, regardless of the venue. Now, that's not to say that any of us agree with government-sponsored firewalls. Quite the opposite. That said, we are professionals here, and helping you circumvent Russia's firewall is inherently unprofessional. In addition to that, you're admittedly trying to increase your network performance for pirating movies, which isn't going to earn you any favors either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're on a windows machine, your best bet is to create a firewall rule that disallows any inbound/outbound traffic to and from your VPN's IP, from the utorrnet client.

IPConfig should show you your VPN IP, and the [Following Article](https://blog.ipredator.se/howto/restricting-utorrent-to-vpn-interfaces-part-3.html) shows you how to block utorrent from accessing specific ip's, simply replace the IP ranges mentioned there, with your VPN IP.

Comment: You shouldn't be penalized b/c the question is OT. +1.